# splitting length (metre) data by interval with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, intervals

I have a dataframe of length-interval data (from boreholes) which looks something like this:

```
df
Out[46]: 
   from  to  min intensity
0     0  10   py        2
1     5  15  cpy       3.5
2    14  27  spy       0.7
```

I need to pivot this data, but also break it on the least common length interval; resulting in the 'min' column as column headers, and the values being the 'rank'. The output would look like this:

```
df.somefunc(index=['from','to'], columns='min', values='intensity', fill_value=0)
Out[47]: 
   from  to  py  cpy  spy
0     0  5   2   0    0
1     5  10  2   3.5  0
2    10  14  0   3.5  0
3    14  15  0   3.5  0.7
4    15  27  0   0    0.7
```

so basically the "From" and "To" describe non-overlapping intervals down a borehole, where the intervals have been split by the least common denominator - as you can see the "py" interval from the original table has been split, the first (0-5m) into py:2, cpy:0 and the second (5-10m) into py:2, cpy:3.5.

The result from just a basic pivot_table function is this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='intensity', index=['from', 'to'], columns="min", aggfunc="first", fill_value=0)
Out[48]: 
min      cpy  py  spy
from to              
0    10    0   2    0
5    15  3.5   0    0
14   27    0   0    0.75
```

which just treats the from and to columns combined as an index. An important point is that my output cannot have overlapping from and to values (IE the subsequent 'from' value cannot be less than the previous 'to' value).

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this using Pandas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know natural interval arithmetic in Pandas, so you need do do it. 
Here a way to do that, If  I correctly understand bound conditions.
This can be a O(n^3) problem, it will create huge table for big entries.

```
# make the new bounds
bounds=np.unique(np.hstack((df["from"],df["to"])))
df2=pd.DataFrame({"from":bounds[:-1],"to":bounds[1:]})

#find inclusions 
isin=df.apply(lambda x :
df2['from'].between(x[0],x[1]-1)
| df2['to'].between(x[0]+1,x[1])
,axis=1).T

#data
data=np.where(isin,df.intensity,0)

#result
df3=pd.DataFrame(data,
pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.values.T),df["min"])
```

For :

```
In [26]: df3
Out[26]: 
min     py  cpy  spy
0  5   2.0  0.0  0.0
5  10  2.0  3.5  0.0
10 14  0.0  3.5  0.0
14 15  0.0  3.5  0.7
15 27  0.0  0.0  0.7
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually a lot fewer lines of code then I thought it would take. Thanks very much!!!